# Parse on node js with cheerio

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I have problem with parse html code on cheerio

Here's the code what i'm need to parse

```
<dd style="">
<p><strong>Version: </strong>0.4.0 (3612) for Android 4.3+ (Jelly Bean MR2, API 18)</p>
<p><strong>Update on: </strong>2018-04-17</p>
<p><strong>Signature: </strong>3ec8cd69d71b7922e2a17445840866b26d86e283</p>
```

I need to parse `0.4.0 (3612) for Android 4.3+ (Jelly Bean MR2, API 18)`, but how to parse only `<p>` without strong?

Here's my parse code :

```
function parseFields ($) {

   const h2 = $('.faq_cat').attr('id');
   const info = $('meta[name="description"]').attr('content');
   const version = $('ddstyle[name="p"]').attr('version')


   const fields = {
     h2,
     info,
     version
   };
```

Comment: Can you provide what you have tried?

Comment: const version = $('ddstyle[name="p"]').attr('version')

Comment: and What is result you are seeing, you should provide code where you start parsing

Comment: it's just giving me `undefined`

Comment: i'm send a parse code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `text` function as following

```
$('dd').find('p').first().text();
```

or if need particular element then use `eq` in the place of `first` like

```
$('dd').find('p').eq(0).text();
```

Comment: but how i can choose second element ?

Comment: I updated answer, please check, index start from 0, you can use 1 for second element in `eq` function argument